# openshift deployment gets stuck executing a rake task in a deploy hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openshift

So I'm having this weird issue when deploying a Rails app on Openshift. The deployment process gets stuck executing a rake task in my deploy hook, which looks like this:

```
pushd ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR} > /dev/null

ln -nfs ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/shared/updates ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/public/updates
ln -nfs ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/shared/downloads ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/public/downloads
ln -nfs ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/shared/uploads ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/public/uploads

echo "exec bundle install --no-deployment"
bundle install --no-deployment --path=vendor/bundle
echo "exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-production}"
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-production}
echo "exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-production}"
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-production}

popd > /dev/null
```

Sometimes it passes fine if I kill the deploy script, log in to the box, run the deploy hook manually and restart Passenger. Sometimes though, the hook script freezes as if the rake task is waiting for some input. After re-running the script commands step by step, everything is fine. I would guess there are some runtime exceptions happening which I don't see for some reason, but I couldn't find any means to actually trace the culprit.

I'm really annoyed because of the downtime caused and the necessity to manually perform tasks that are supposed to be automated. Anyone have any idea what might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try redirecting the output of the scripts to a log file in your $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR so that you can see what is going on? 
`bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-production} >>$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/deploy.log 2>&1`